# Localization of Root.plist don't work

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, localization, settings

I have my app localized in three languages and this runs as it should. I added a settings.bundle to the app and I can make changes in the settings and that works too. But I have serious problems with the localization. As suggested in other forums I created in Finder the two additional folders de.lproj and fr.lproj. Into them I copied the Root.strings. My Root.plist is a simple version with one group-item for the title and one Multi Value item with three titles/values inside. The titles/values doesn't need to be translated, but the both titles of the items.

My Root.strings have the following content:

```
"language" = "Sprache";
"selectedlanguage" = "Ihre Sprachwahl";
```

The "language" and the "selectedlanguage" are the values of the strings in the Root.plist wich shoulod be replaced:

```
<plist version=1.0">
<dict>
<key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
 <array>
      <dict>
           <key>Title</key>
           <string>language</string>
           <key>Type</key>
           <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
           <key>Type</key>
           <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
           <key>Title</key>
           <string>selectedlanguage</string>
           ....
      </dict>
  </array>
 <key>StringsTable</key>
 <string>Root</string>
```

How can I set up the localization to work? Is there a specific way to create the Root.strings or to "implement" them?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems to be a simulator problem. On my iPhone it works.